# How to make responsive sidebar?

Tags: menu, navigation, responsive

I am now making a website. I need a sidebar that has a sub navigation menu which is responsive. I have been searching through the web but just couldn't get what i want.

**I want something like this**
http://www.thomasphilip.com.my/careers/

Not sure if there is any website has tutorial about this kind of subnav? Any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would simply require using a media query to rework the navigation.  You should examine the elements of that reference web site when set to different sizes if you want to get something similar.

Here's another resource: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

The example shown moves the nav around.  It doesn't change from a row layout to a spinner, but that's just a matter of figuring out how you want to implement each of those.

Comment: This is actually not what i wanted. I want it to be same as the website i was referring to. When it's on small layout, the submenu will be responsive. Can click to choose the option i wanted to go.